# Does crying because of a sin break the wudu or invalidate prayer?

Tags: salat, wudu

If one cries in prayer out of remorse and guilt for a sin that he committed invalidate the prayer or the wudu?

I know crying due to worldly affairs invalidates the prayer but what if you cry out of fear of having committed a sin?

Comment: _crying due to worldly affairs invalidates the prayer_ --- How is so?

Comment: I doubt if it would break wudu, but it could invalidate a prayer! As you may add something to a prayer which isn#t part of it, as if you would speak or shake hands ...

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Wtpmp1I5M0 . Here you will see the Imam and others crying during salah. Do you still think Salah/Wudu becomes invalidated due to tears?  If you read here: http://www.islamsight.org/en/najas-the-dirty-things.html , you will find all the najas that breaks wudu.

Comment: Although you may see such videos it is not recommended to make others cry during prayer and scholars reject such an act especially if an Imam did this intentionally in all or most of his prayers if it was what we may call a spontaneous reaction that would be alright!

Comment: Right. Crying your heart out to Allah is encouraged in Islam. That is the first step towards repentance. I was only trying to show that crying is not a bad thing and tears can never be najas.